# Extract newline-terminated string from null-terminated string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, network-programming

I have a buffer string which contains network-received data. I would like to get in another string all the characters until the next `\n` and remove those characters (as well as the `\n`) from the buffer string.
How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to to it, this is how:

```
if buffer.find("\n") != -1:
    packet = buffer[:buffer.find("\n")]
    buffer = buffer[buffer.find("\n")+1:]
```

Comment: `if len(buffer.split('\n')) > 1 : return buffer.split('\n') ` mean #1 packet, #2 buffer